# Use a single WP installation instead of three

Tags: multisite, installation

I have an already running website, say `www.example.com` and I want to add a few extra sections to it, they'll be `News`, `Career` and `Case Studies` whose links need to be

```
www.example.com/news/
www.example.com/career/
www.example.com/case-studies/
```

The content is similar to how a blog post is so a wordpress blog is best suited as a CMS for these pages. What I wanted to do was to install wordpress in the root of the website and use categories for `News`, `Career` and `Case Studies`. These categories would create links like this

```
www.example.com/category/news/
www.example.com/category/career/
www.example.com/category/case-studies/
```

This is fine but the problem is I already have an `index.php` file in the root and deleting or renaming the wordpress's `index.php` broke the whole installation. So what would be a solution to get category links like above while still keeping my existing site intact.

Is it possible to install wp in a subdirectory but have the links like `www.example.com/news/` or to rename the `index.php` to something else so it doesn't clash with older files of `example.com`? If nothing works, I'll have to have three installations of wordpress each in it's own subdirectory which I would keep as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have main web site which is not WordPress, but you want to implement WordPress Blog inside it, and create premalinks/categories as you described.

If I were handling this requirement, I would go about it by installing separated WP instance on subdomain, such as `blog.example.com` , and then create categories like this

```
blog.example.com/category/news/
blog.example.com/category/career/
blog.example.com/category/case-studies/
```

Additionally, you can create HTTP 301 redirection(s), and "map" some virtual URL-s to your blog. For example, you can `map www.example.com/category/news/ to blog.example.com/category/news/` , so if user visits category on main page it will be redirected to appropriate sub domain.

Technical details:
HTTP Redirection(s) are usually created inside .htaccess file, good tutorial about this can be found on page, http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess

Example HTTP 301 redirection would look like this:

```
Redirect 301 /category/news/ http://blog.example.com/category/news
```

**Important note:** *Creating multiple WordPress installations just to cover different categories is not an option. It will cause you various of issues in future (updates, same design, multiple plugins, analytics, tracking).*